# Building custom Go Plugin

Tags: go, kustomize

I'm in the process of creating a custom transformer for kustomize.  However, I'm running into issues creating even the most basic Go Plugin.  I'm trying to follow these steps here https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/docs/plugins/goPluginGuidedExample.md

I'm using one of the plugins in mainline kustomize, ie. `secretsfromdatabase` [1]

According to the documentation, the instructions I'm following are:

```sh
tmpGoPath=$(mktemp -d)
GOPATH=$tmpGoPath go install sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize
GOPATH=$tmpGoPath go build -buildmode plugin -o SecretsFromDatabase.so SecretsFromDatabase.go
cp SecretsFromDatabase.so ~/.config/kustomize/plugin/mygenerators/sopsencodedsecrets/SopsEncodedSecrets
```

Now when I run kustomize, I get the following error:

```sh
Error: accumulating resources: recursed accumulation [...] fails to load: plugin.Open("$HOME/.config/kustomize/plugin/mygenerators/sopsencodedsecrets/SopsEncodedSecrets"): plugin was built with a different version of package internal/cpu
```

What is strange is I'm using the same tag in git as the version that is installed on my system.

```sh
kustomize version                                                                                                                                                     tags/kustomize/v3.5.4^0
{Version:3.5.4 GitCommit:3af514fa9f85430f0c1557c4a0291e62112ab026 BuildDate:2020-01-17T14:23:25+00:00 GoOs:darwin GoArch:amd64}
```

[1] https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/tree/master/plugin/someteam.example.com/v1/secretsfromdatabase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for now plugins are very difficult to write and support because the environment should be identical and in practice only original build system can reliably build the plugins. In result a lot of people like you finding little differences in their build environments. I think it is bad idea from design and strongly recommend to get acquainted with Reddit discussion [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/b6h8qq/is_anyone_actually_using_go_plugins/)

Comment: Thank you for linking this reddit.  I was wonder why I was having a difficult time but know i understand the complexity and the reason why this is not a good approach.